# Rocket attacks dataset in Israel and State of Palestine

Tags: data-request, military

I'm looking for a dataset listing the rocket attacks in Israel and the State of Palestine with  as many following fields as possible:

- timestamp
- GPS
- number of casualties
- reason for attack (e.g. a pointer to a previous attack)
- number of articles covering the attack

Period covered should be as large as possible, but mostly interested from 2000 to now.

Comment: That's probably impossible to establish.  Who are you going to trust on casualty numbers?

Comment: Most datasets are noisy, that's life.

Comment: From the question title I thought you were saying a Rocket had attacked datasets.

Comment: Israeli human rights NGO B'Tselem is publishing [statistics](http://www.btselem.org/statistics), unfortunately no API or otherwise open access yet. They keep track in more processable data formats and might cooperate if you contact them.

Answer (score 6):

Try the [Global Terrorism Database](http://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/) from the [National Consortium for the Study of Terrorism and Responses to Terrorism (START)](http://www.start.umd.edu/) project at at the University of Maryland. Here's a brief snip from their [about page](http://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/about/)

> The Global Terrorism Database (GTD) is an open-source database
>   including information on terrorist events around the world from 1970
>   through 2012 (with additional annual updates planned for the future).
>   Unlike many other event databases, the GTD includes systematic data on
>   domestic as well as transnational and international terrorist
>   incidents that have occurred during this time period and now includes
>   more than 113,000 cases. For each GTD incident, information is
>   available on the date and location of the incident, the weapons used
>   and nature of the target, the number of casualties, and--when
>   identifiable--the group or individual responsible.

The GTD database can be downloaded after filling out a form at http://apps.start.umd.edu/gtd/contact/ -- so "kind of open data."

[START got the contract to collect terrorism data](http://www.start.umd.edu/news/state-department-contracts-start-provide-terrorism-data-and-analysis) for the US State Dep.
after [WITS: the Worldwide Incidents Tracking System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldwide_Incidents_Tracking_System) was discontinued in 2012.

Some of the original WITS website is in [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://wits.nctc.gov/) This [page of reports](https://web.archive.org/web/20111014233722/https://wits.nctc.gov/FederalDiscoverWITS/index.do?N=0) has a link for "exports" at the top, but they didn't seem to work for me.

Also, I found the [RAND Database of Worldwide Terrorism Incidents](http://www.rand.org/nsrd/projects/terrorism-incidents.html), although that only covers 1968-2009 according to their [database scope](http://www.rand.org/nsrd/projects/terrorism-incidents/about/definitions.html) page.

Comment: Thanks! Yes we need a Wayback Machine for datasets, given the rate at which they disappear...

Comment: good idea about the wayback machine. I checked it and added a little more info.

Answer (score 5):

There is a new API for journalists and others called [CrisisNET](http://crisis.net). With it you can search based on location and type. Also, you can export CSV files if you aren't familiar with programming - **[explore](http://crisis.net/explore/)**.

Inside of the returned data are some URLs for more details. Typical results in JSON format will have these fields:

```
{   "remoteID": "117721645006819_543803659065280",   "language": {
    "nativeName": "العربية",
    "code": "ar",
    "name": "Arabic"   },   "license": "facebook",   "author": {
    "username": "gazanews2012",
    "remoteID": "gazanews2012",
    "name": "شبكة غزة لأخبار العاجلة"   },   "contentEnglish": "URGENT: rocket in \"slogan Negev\", causing material damage",   "fromURL": "http://facebook.com/117721645006819_543803659065280",   "publishedAt": "2014-06-18T18:43:47+00:00",   "summary": "عاجل: سقوط صاروخ في \"شعار هنيغف\" محدثاً أضرار مادية",   "content": "عاجل: سقوط صاروخ في \"شعار هنيغف\" محدثاً أضرار مادية",   "source": "facebook",   "tags": [
    {
      "confidence": 1,
      "name": "armed-conflict"
    },
    {
      "confidence": 1,
      "name": "conflict"
    }   ],   "lifespan": "temporary",   "updatedAt": "2014-06-18T20:11:19.553522",   "entities": [
    "Gaza Strip"   ],   "geo": {
    "coords": [
      34.44580841064453,
      31.524253845214844
    ],
    "locationIdentifiers": {
      "authorLocationName": "gaza غزة"
    },
    "addressComponents": {
      "adminArea4": "Gaza Strip",
      "streetAddress": "Street",
      "formattedAddress": "Street"
    }   },   "id": "ljHUik-aQequcQtc21StvQ",   "createdAt": "2014-06-18T20:06:13.661308" },
```