# 2014 Ebola outbreak dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for a dataset on the 2014 Ebola outbreak with as many following fields as possible:

For each individual contaminated with ebola:

- Estimated datetime and location of detection
- Datetime and location of detection
- Datetime and location of death (if fatal)
- Cause of contamination
- Gender and age

So far I found [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/2cn28o/2014_ebola_outbreak_cases_deaths_oc/), which pulls data that can also be found at the [2014 West Africa Ebola outbreak Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_West_Africa_Ebola_outbreak) Unfortunately, the location data I've seen is the country.

[image]
*West Africa Ebola 2014 actual case and death linear scale - CC BY-SA 4.0 -
[Malanoqa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola_virus_epidemic_in_West_Africa#mediaviewer/File:West_Africa_Ebola_2014_actual_case_and_death_linear_scale.png)*

Are there any more detailed datasets out there?

Comment: Where have you looked so far?

Comment: @alancalvitti Added in question.

Comment: open street maps is currently working on this...check out osm

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're looking for a line listing. There are no case data available for this outbreak, but like Skram said, I collect and maintain data from various sources on [github](https://github.com/cmrivers/ebola). Sierra Leone and Liberia release some case data on the province/county level; Liberia's data is quite good. The WHO used to include town names for Guinea, but it has since stopped doing that. Another thing to be aware of is that the only dates for this outbreak are report dates. We have nothing on onset dates, hospitalization dates, death dates, etc. My contact info is on my github, feel free to write if you want to chat more. -Caitlin

Answer (score 8):

Did you try the World Health Organization?

http://www.who.int/csr/don/en/

Looks like July 1, 2014 is when they started providing the chart data. The data gets updated every few days.

Comment: I also see, there's a PDF with geolocations of infections. It is still aggregate data, but perhaps you can contact the mapmakers for more details.

http://www.who.int/csr/disease/ebola/2014-0728-donor-update-ebola-final.pdf?ua=1

Answer (score 8):

Also take a look at https://github.com/cmrivers/ebola . Caitlin Rivers (@cmyeaton on Twitter) is a PhD student in computational epidemiology and is curating this data from a number of sources.

Answer (score 6):

WHO and the CDC get their data directly from the effected countries ministry of health.
These countries are:

- Liberia http://www.mohsw.gov.lr/content_display.php?press_id=94&sub=press_release
  Lastest Report - http://mohsw.gov.lr/documents/Liberia%20Ebola%20SitRep%2089%20Aug%2012,%202014.pdf
- Sierra Leone http://health.gov.sl/?page_id=583
  Latest Report - http://health.gov.sl/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Ebola-Situation-Report_Vol-78.pdf
- Nigeria http://health.gov.ng/
- Guinea - does not have an online MOH site
- Democratic Republic of Congo - http://www.minisanterdc.cd
- Senegal - http://www.sante.gouv.sn (site is down)

International Sources:
WHO - http://www.who.int/csr/don/archive/disease/ebola/en/
CDC - http://www.cdc.gov/vhf/ebola/resources/distribution-map-guinea-outbreak.html
 
International SOS - https://www.internationalsos.com/ebola/index.cfm?content_id=421&language_id=ENG

Answer (score 5):

Here is an attempt at a list, there is a link to subscribe to the wiki and receive updates to pages you watch:
http://ebola-wiki.com/List_of_Ebola_related_data_sources

Comment: It's interesting to see a timely-named domain. Sort of like www.sevenforums.com/ for Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

Sierra Leone, Liberia, and Guinea data can be downloaded as CSV or JSON from [WHO](http://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.ebola-sitrep.quick-downloads?lang=en)

Answer (score 4):

Another source is this healthmap.org visualization at http://healthmap.org/ebola/#.

If you take a look at the XHR requests for `http://healthmap.org/ebola/content/markers.json` and `http://healthmap.org/ebola/content/links.json`, you *might* be able to extract some data from there. I'd also suggest getting in contact with the HealthMap folks. They are very good people.

Answer (score 4):

(Modified from [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3425/1511).)

There is a new API for journalists and others called [CrisisNET](http://crisis.net). With it you can search based on location and type. Also, you can use the API and even export CSV files if you aren't familiar with programming.

**[Explore the API](http://crisis.net/explore/)**.

[image: example of ebola query]

Answer (score 4):

One more data source and analytical tool that is Liberia-specific: http://ebolainliberia.org/

Answer (score 3):

here's another source with a few datasets:
https://data.hdx.rwlabs.org/ebola
edit update
they just released an api
http://docs.hdx.rwlabs.org/an-api-for-ebola-data/

Answer (score 3):

The open data repository at [eboladata.org](http://www.eboladata.org) provides a compilation of nearly all data sources on Ebola that are available.

Answer (score 3):

A new geospatial data portal for the Ebola outbreak was recently launched by a group of international organizations:

http://ebolageonode.org

Answer (score 3):

Many sites provide data, but a few work to normalize the metadata and validate the data itself.  Try:

- The United Nations HDX (Humanitarian Data Exchange) [ebola site](https://data.hdx.rwlabs.org/ebola)
- The Africa Open Data group's [EbolaData.org](https://eboladata.gov) site

(Note: I serve as a co-chair for the [Africa Open Data group](http://www.meetup.com/Africa-Open-Data/))